# How does MultiLanguage search engines Work

Tags: search, elasticsearch, youtube, full-text-search, google-search

Today , when searching some videos on youtube i found out that youtube can return relevant results even if you search for videos in languages other than english.

Tried searching about this on google , but all i got was some api's to do this programmatically.Can someone throw some light on the theory behind this.Papers/Links/Explanations,anything  would do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When I've done this with elasticsearch, I've simply mapped multiple fields for each document, like:

```
"text_val": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "en": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "english"
    },
    "it": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "italian"
    }
  }
}
```

And then just search both fields for every query. This works well and is good enough for many applications. However I'm sure Google is doing something much more complex, certainly language identification on both the indexed documents and the query. In case you want to do language identification, I've used [python langid](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py) before and had good results.

The problem you're going to face using elasticsearch for this kind of thing, in my experience, isn't the multi-language part, but that the analyzers for languages other than English don't always work as well as you would like. You may have to write a custom analyzer, with rules to handle lots of special cases, and tuned for your specific dataset.